# Oxwall - Newsfeed limit on wall

Tags: php, smarty, socialengine, oxwall

How can I increase newsfeed limit on oxwall wall. By default it allows 40 only. Where I can customize code to make it like 100,150??

I know that file which need to modify is : ow_plugins/newsfeed/components/feed_widget.php

But do not know which code need to modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do by following :

Go to : public_html/ow_plugins/newsfeed/components/feed_widget.php

Line 100:

```
'optionList' => array(2 => '2', 3 => '3', 4 => '4', 5 => '5', 6 => '6', 7 => '7', 8 => '8', 9 =>  '9', 10 => '10', 11 => '11', 12 => '12', 13 => '13', 14 => '14', 15 => '15', 16 => '16', 17 => '17', 18  => '18', 19 => '19', 20 => '20', 25 => '25', '30' => 30, '40' => 40),
```

Add array till you need like 100,150.